# Add Bootstrap class-names to Typo3 tables

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typo3

Is there a possibility to add Bootstrap table-classes to tables created in Typo3 v6.1? I have noticed the setting "Additional CSS Class" when creating a page of type "Table", but:

1. it doesn't add any classes to my table
2. it doesn't support adding multiple classes (commas, spaces etc. get stripped when saving)

I would to add `class="table table-hover"` to any table I create. Also, I don't think that I need the default class "contenttable".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your post, I assume that you are using the content element table, not a table in the RTE.

Overriding the classes of the RTE would be easy (in TypoScript setup):

```
lib.parseFunc_RTE {
    externalBlocks {
        table.stdWrap.HTMLparser.tags.table.fixAttrib.class {
            default = table table-hover
            always = 1
            list >
        }
    }
}
```

(The TYPO3 default is "contenttable".)

Overriding the classes of the table CE is harder. Only the FlexForm value is respected, if it is not set, it falls back to the standard classes, see https://git.typo3.org/Packages/TYPO3.CMS.git/blob/HEAD:/typo3/sysext/css_styled_content/Classes/Controller/CssStyledContentController.php#l130

You will find two solutions in [How to generate <table> compatible with jQueryMobile in TYPO3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155150/how-to-generate-table-compatible-with-jquerymobile-in-typo3). The first one seems the best to me, the second one looks very hacky.

Comment: I was hoping I could use the page-type "Table", but fortunately it's no big deal in my current case and I will use a RTE table. Thanks a lot! 

(PS: for the second case, I'd probably add the classes using jQuery–didn't think of that before)

Comment: Today I noticed, the above TypoScript only works in 6.x

Comment: Any solution for this in typo 4.5.x ?

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in the TYPO3 core, so you can use multiple classes in the regular table element now. [See Bugfix #55470 on forge](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/55470)