# Typo3: How to remove empty paragraphs on page

Tags: html, formatting, typo3, paragraphs

I'm using Typo3 v6.1 to create a standard page of the type “text”. In the view, Typo3 adds four empty paragraphs before and after the content created on the Rich Text Editor.

```
<p class="bodytext">&nbsp;</p>
<p class="bodytext">    <!--  CONTENT ELEMENT, uid:17/text [begin] --></p>
<p class="bodytext">        <a id="c17"></a></p>
<p class="bodytext">        <!--  Text: [begin] --></p>    

<p class="bodytext">The actual text added using the Rich Text Editor</p>    

<p class="bodytext">        <!--  Text: [end] --></p>
<p class="bodytext">&nbsp;</p>
<p class="bodytext">    <!--  CONTENT ELEMENT, uid:17/text [end] --></p>
<p class="bodytext">&nbsp;</p>
```

It goes without saying, that I'd like to get rid off this clutter, especially since the `&nbsp;` are breaking the layout.

Comment: You should add relevant typoscript, used extensions, TYPO3 Verison etc.

Answer (score 8):

There is a parseFunc < lib.parseFunc_RTE at the wrong place.

Looks like you have something like

```
page.10 = CONTENT
page.10.stdWrap.parseFunc < lib.parseFunc_RTE
```

Which would mean: render the content, and after that parse this content with lib.parseFunc_RTE. The code which activates the wrapping is

```
lib.parseFunc_RTE.nonTypoTagStdWrap.encapsLines.wrapNonWrappedLines = <p>|</p>
```

Removing would not solve the issue here, because the cause is, that lib.parseFunc_RTE is processed on the whole content element and not only on bodytext where it should be defined.

Have a look in your TypoScript or add it to your question.

**for testing purpose:**

Create a new Site on top level, and add only basic TypoScript (add css_styled_content template; Check clear setup and constants)

```
page = PAGE
page.10 < styles.content.get
```

Check that output, the content should not wrapped into **p class="bodytext"** anymore.

**Update:**

Using {content} where {content} is filled via styles.content.get f.e. the parseFunc is executed twice. styles.content.get executeds the parseFunc, so it can be outputted to the browser. But f:format.html executed lib.parseFunc too. So, that is, why your content is parsed twice.

```
# in this case, f:format.html does not need to execute the parseFunc again
<f:format.html  parseFuncTSPath="">{content}</f:format.html>
```

Use lib.parseFunc_RTE if you have an RTE field, use lib.parseFunc if you do not expect HTML-Code in the field (f.e. header).

Comment: I just did a clean install (this time using 6.0 instead of 6.1) and it keeps happening. The only code in my template that affects `lib.parseFunc_RTE` is taken from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648083/add-bootstrap-class-names-to-typo3-tables). However, when I remove that, I still get those empty lines. When using a plugin like News, Typo3 even adds 30 empty paragraphs before the first heading.

Comment: TYPO3 does not adds 30 empty paragraphs out of the box. It depends on your configuration, your template-files or perhaps an installed extension.

Answer (score 6):

add following lines in template script of root

In Constants :

```
content.RTE_compliant = 0
```

In Setup :

```
tt_content.stdWrap.dataWrap >
lib.parseFunc_RTE.nonTypoTagStdWrap.encapsLines>
```

Comment: lib.parseFunc_RTE.nonTypoTagStdWrap.encapsLines> does the job for my own parse func

Comment: lib.parseFunc_RTE.nonTypoTagStdWrap.encapsLines> does the job even in 2021 in TYPO3  10

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution to **a variant** of the problem described in the post.

```
<f:format.html>
   {field.copyrightText}
</f:format.html>
```

gives you one paragraph before and after the expected paragraph

```
<f:format.html>{field.copyrightText}</f:format.html>
```

gives you no additional paragraphs. So the breaks in a template seem to be parsed by the format viewHelper.

hope this helps someone; have a good day

Comment: Perfect thanks, that helps also in TYPO3 8.7.12 to remove the empty paragraphs. I used this for usage for Resource-Relation on Page-Properties without any RTE inside - just the Image-Description aka Caption.

Answer (score 0):

I did some more research and stumbled across people running into the same problem. The `div` tags and the comments are the result of so-called "CSS Styled Content". This content is passed to the frontend using `content < styles.content.get`, which is—according to my Fluid templating tutorial–the common way to pass content from the RTE to the template.

One website described these as solution (or workaround):

```
# standard enclosure for header
lib.stdheader.10.1.fontTag = <h1>|</h1>    

# remove .csc-header
lib.stdheader.stdWrap.dataWrap >    

# plain headings
lib.stdheader.2.headerStyle >
lib.stdheader.3.headerClass >    

# (unknown, german version read "remove other stuff"
tt_content.stdWrap.dataWrap =    

# disable .bodytext in RTE paragraphs
lib.parseFunc_RTE.nonTypoTagStdWrap.encapsLines.addAttributes.P.class >    

# disable paragraph-enclosure for these tags
lib.parseFunc_RTE.nonTypoTagStdWrap.encapsLines.encapsTagList = cite, div, p, pre, hr, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6,table,tr,td    

# remove paragraphs in tables
#lib.parseFunc_RTE.externalBlocks.table.stdWrap.HTMLparser.removeTags = p    

# allow classes in tables
lib.parseFunc_RTE.externalBlocks.table.stdWrap.HTMLparser.tags.table.fixAttrib.class.list >
```

**Warning:** I can not speak for the quality of this workaround. It did solve most problems (divs, comments and classes were removed), but the `p` tags remained.

Comment: now, we know you work with fluid. If you would like to understand what happens, it can be helpfull to show the part of the HTML-Template and the according TypoScript.

Comment: In my template I'm using a simple `<f:format.html>{content}</f:format.html>` and the TypoScript mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

Can be corrected by removing linebreaks/spaces inside format.html tag

Incorrect:

`<f:format.html>{data_item.tx_mask_content_rte}
</f:format.html>`

Correct
`<f:format.html>{data_item.tx_mask_content_rte}</f:format.html>`

Same applies to `<f:format.date>`, where having linebreaks/spaces can lead to fatal errors.

Again poorly handled by fluid imho.

Hope it helps

Comment: this is a correct answer... but also here 4 month ago

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too, sometimes it helped to use this setup:

`lib.parseFunc_RTE.nonTypoTagStdWrap.encapsLines>`

But it cased that I wasn't able to use 
 in the tables. So I jump a little bit inside and found this possibility:

`lib.parseFunc_RTE.nonTypoTagStdWrap.encapsLines.innerStdWrap_all.ifBlank =`

Answer (score -1):

Here is what did the job for me, I added the following line to my setup.

```
config.disablePrefixComment = 1
```

Comment: This is not a real solution for the problem. It just configures TYPO3 to not render the comments like "CONTENT ELEMENT". So maybe it looks OK for you, but there is still a configuration problem.

Answer (score -5):

Please add this code above the end of body tag,

> ```
> <script>
>    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
>    var elemsLenght = elems.length;
>    for (var i = 0; i < elemsLenght; ++i) {
>        if (elems[i].innerHTML == '' || elems[i].innerHTML == ' ' || >elems[i].innerHTML == '&nbsp;')
>       { 
>           elems[i].innerHTML="";
>           elems[i].className="";
>       }
>     }
>  </script>
> ```

Comment: Not a clean solution. How if the user doesnt have javascript. I think you can get ride of the prob qith TYPO3