# Set a default class on table when adding one in the RTE

Tags: typo3, rte

I'm looking for a way to add a default `class` on `table` in the RTE view in the Backend.

When I create a `table` in the RTE, the output in backend is the following:

```
<table summary="" cellspacing="" cellpadding="" dir="">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">blabla</th>
      <th scope="col">blabla</th>
      <th scope="col">blabla</th>
      <th scope="col">blabla</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>blabla</td>
      <td>blabla</td>
      <td>blabla</td>
      <td>blabla</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

What can I make to add a `class="myclass"` to it ?

```
<table class="myclass" summary="" cellspacing="" cellpadding="" dir="">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">blabla</th>
      <th scope="col">blabla</th>
      <th scope="col">blabla</th>
      <th scope="col">blabla</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>blabla</td>
      <td>blabla</td>
      <td>blabla</td>
      <td>blabla</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: Edit table code in the RTE]

My config:

- TYPO3 4.7.10
- htmlArea RTE (rtehtmlarea) 4.7.7

Thanks for your help !

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648083/add-bootstrap-class-names-to-typo3-tables, it is documented there.

Comment: ... but nice description BTW!

Comment: @lorenz As I understand http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648083/add-bootstrap-class-names-to-typo3-tables , this is for the fronted rendering. My question is about the backend. When I create a table in RTE how to automatically add `class="contestable"` in it.

thx about the documentation ;)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see there is no option to set a default table style or blockstyle on a table. Take a look in the source: typo3/sysext/rtehtmlarea/Resources/Public/JavaScript/Plugins/TableOperations.js

The closest you can get is choosing your style when creating the table.

You will need a piece of TSConfig:

```
RTE {
    classes {
        contenttable {
            name = Content table
            value =
        }
    }

    default {
        contentCSS = EXT:some_plugin/Resources/Public/StyleSheets/RichTextEditor.css

        buttons {
            blockstyle {
                tags {
                    table.allowedClasses := addToList(contenttable)
                }
            }
        }

        proc {
            entryHTMLparser_db = 1
            entryHTMLparser_db {
                tags {
                    table {
                        allowedAttribs := addToList(class)
                    }
                }
            }

            allowedClasses := addToList(contenttable)
        }
    }
}
```

And the stylesheet: some_plugin/Resources/Public/StyleSheets/RichTextEditor.css

```
table.contenttable {
    border: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
}

table.contenttable td {
    padding: 0.5em;
}

table.contentable thead {
    background: #b2ebaf;
}

table.contenttable th {
    background-color: #00a2dd;
    color: #171717;
}

table.contenttable th {
    border: 1px none #00a2dd;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 3px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

table.contenttable th {
    border-style: solid none solid none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

td.align-left {
    text-align: left;
}

td.align-right {
    text-align: right;
}

td.align-center {
    text-align: center;
}

td.align-justify {
    text-align: justify;
}
```

This will allow selecting the 'Content table' style for the whole table in the backend.